# Tree with recursive template exceeding call stack

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, tree

Using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72), I can display a tree without issue..

[image]

I would like to treat the first level a little differently and display it like so:

[image]

I have tried a few different variation but I keep exceeding the call stack, example ts here:

```
<h1>Angular 2 Recursive List</h1>
<ul>

    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      {{item.title}} - LEVEL 0
      <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">

        <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
          <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
            {{child.title}}
            <ul *ngIf="child.children.length > 0">
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: child.children }"></ng-container>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: child }"></ng-container>


      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Error:

```
preview-d2335ca5bdb955611c1cb.js:1 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (ng_for_of.ts:212)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:215)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:429)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:389)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (services.ts:431)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (services.ts:392)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:386)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:359)
    at callViewAction (view.ts:615)
```

[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcxhhr)

Comment: Reason for down-vote?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to simplify things a little bit.

I created a separate `list-item` component in order to easily spot errors.

#### list-item.component.ts

```
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() children: any[];
  @Input('index') nestingLayer = 0;
```

#### list-item.component.html

```html
<p [ngStyle]="{ 'margin-left': nestingLayer + 'rem' }">
  {{ title }}
</p>

<ng-container *ngIf="children.length">
  <app-list-item
    *ngFor="let item of children"
    [children]="item.children"
    [title]="item.title"
    [index]="nestingLayer + 1"
  ></app-list-item>
</ng-container>
```

And finally, your list container

```html
<ul>
  <app-list-item 
    *ngFor="let item of list"
    [title]="item.title"
    [children]="item.children"
  ></app-list-item>
</ul>
```

[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gdfd4?file=src/app/app.component.ts).